# Deepcopy causes "Class" has no attribute 'size'

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, pass-by-reference, deep-copy

I am currently trying to implement parallel execution of a process. For each of these processes, every process should create a copy of an object "A", and then proceed with this object.

What I have is the following:

```
from copy import deepcopy

def some_A():
    def wrapper_singlerun(_):
        return single_run(self, t_kernel, X, Y)

    pool = pathos.multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    all_responses = pool.map(wrapper_singlerun, 100)

def single_run(self, t_kernel, X, Y):
    t_kernel = deepcopy(t_kernel) # <<< This line fails
    ...
```

Notice that the two functions are NOT within the same class! (the self is just supposed to be an object dictionary to be able to access fields from that object. These fields are never modified though).

However, when I apply the above functions, I get the following error:

```
self = <bacode.tripathy.src.bilionis_refactor.t_kernel.TripathyMaternKernel object at 0x1a0e6f5ba8>

@property
def param_array(self):
    """
        Array representing the parameters of this class.
        There is only one copy of all parameters in memory, two during optimization.

        !WARNING!: setting the parameter array MUST always be done in memory:
        m.param_array[:] = m_copy.param_array
        """
    if (self.__dict__.get('_param_array_', None) is None) or (self._param_array_.size != self.size):
```

> ```
>       self._param_array_ = np.empty(self.size, dtype=np.float64)
> ```
>
> E           AttributeError: 'TripathyMaternKernel' object has no attribute 'size'

```
 /Users/davidal/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramz/core/parameter_core.py:349: AttributeError
```

I used to get a similar error by pickling the object when using multiprocessing. However, I cannot quite understand why it happens this time. Do I need to copy the `t_kernel` object differently? Any ideas why the above function fails?

Comment: Aside from the fact that accessing the attributes via `self.__dict__` is **probably** not the right thing to do, you need to provide us with the actual code. The `self =` line is a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: The actual code is a little bit long. The `self = ` ist spit out during the error message. The `t_kernel` is of type `TripathyMaternKernel`. What else of the code would you like to see?